# How to select and save stored procedure body?

Tags: php, mariadb

I'm trying to add a workflow in a PHP project that uses a number of Mariadb stored procedures and functions. I tried

```
SELECT * FROM `proc` where db = "db_name"
```

but the user has limited rights. If I try

```
SHOW CREATE PROCEDURE proc_name
```

I get a result set but

> Create procedure is NULL

What else can I try?

EDIT (on request) the php code:

```php
$result = $db->query( 'SHOW CREATE FUNCTION customer_fullname' );
foreach( $result as $row ) {
  $proc   = $row['Function'];
  $source = $row['Create Function'];
  echo "<h1>$proc</h1>";
  echo "<pre>$source</pre>";
}
```

`$proc` is populated, `$source` is null.

Comment: This is a PHP issue or database issue? Please add PHP code if it is a PHP specific issue

Comment: and why has the user not the right rights if he should see the content

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The procedure code is visible only to the procdure creator or to the user that has SELECT permissions to the mysql.proc. From [the documentation](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/show-create-procedure/):

> Both statements (`SHOW CREATE FUNCTION`/`SHOW CREATE PROCEDURE`) require that you are the owner of the routine or have the SELECT privilege on the mysql.proc table. When neither is true, the statements display NULL for the Create Procedure or Create Function field.

What is the workflow you are trying create with reading the procedure body? This is not a common thing to do.

Comment: The work flow is 1) create one file per mysql stored procedure/function. 2) Add these to a source controlled folder. 3) update the database when new version arrive. In other words put the stored procedures/function under source control.

Comment: But indeed the reason was the definer was root and the database connection was using the application db credentials.

Comment: Note from MariaDB-11.3 there is a [SHOW CREATE ROUTINE](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/grant/#database-privileges) database level grant that can be explicitly granted to access non-definer stored procedures and functions.